# I am creating Careers form and Contact Us form in single page website? I have an issue in using the form Submit Buttons?

Tags: html, forms

I am creating Careers FORM and Contact Us FORM in single page website? I have an Issue in using the form Submit Buttons?

The Issue is during validation of the input boxes, how to show difference between the two submit buttons (One SUBMIT button is for Careers form, and another is for Contact us form).

```
    /* CAREER FORM SAMPLE CODE */
    <form method="post" action="index.html" id="careerform">
    <input id="cname" type="text" class="commonstyle comdesign" placeholder="Your name">
    <span id="cnameinfo" class="spandesign0"></span>
    <input id="bigbutton" type="submit" class="commonstyle" value="creer" />
    </form>
    /* CAREER FORM SAMPLE CODE */
    /* CAREER FORM SAMPLE VALIDATION CODE IN JQUERY */
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var career=$("#careerform");

    var cname=$("#cname");
    var cnameinfo=$("#cnameinfo");

    cname.blur(validateCname);

    career.submit.click(function(){
    if(validateCname()){
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    });

    <!-- Name -->
    function validateCname(){
    var cnam=$("#cname").val();
    var regexp0 =/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(cname.val().length < 3 || cname.val().length > 10){
    cnameinfo.text("Atleast 3 letters!");
    return false;
    }
    else{
    if(regexp0.test(cnam))
    {
    cnameinfo.text("OK!");
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    cnameinfo.text("Field Required");
    return false;
    }
    }
    }
    });
    </script>
    <!-- Name -->
    /* CAREER FORM SAMPLE VALIDATION CODE IN JQUERY */

    /* CONTACT US FORM SAMPLE CODE */
    <form method="post" action="index.html" id="conform">
    <span id="nameinfo" class="spandesign"></span>
    <input id="conname" class="constyle comdesign" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input id="consubmit" type="submit" class="constyle" value="ctact" />
    </form>
    /* CONTACT US FORM SAMPLE CODE */

    /* CONTACT US FORM SAMPLE VALIDATION CODE IN JQUERY */
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var form=$("#conform");

    var nameinfo=$("#nameinfo");
    var name=$("#conname");

    name.blur(validateName);
    form.submit.click(function(){
    if(validateName() & validateEmail() & validateCon() & validateSubj() & validateInfo())   
    {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    });
    <!-- Name -->
    function validateName(){
    var nam=$("#conname").val();
    var regnum =/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(name.val().length < 3 || name.val().length > 10){
    nameinfo.text("Atleast 3 letters!");
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    if(regnum.test(nam))
    {
    nameinfo.text("OK!");
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    nameinfo.text("Field Required");
    return false;
    }
    }
    }
    <!-- Name -->
    });
    </script>
    /* CONTACT US FORM SAMPLE VALIDATION CODE IN JQUERY */
```

THIS IS THE SAMPLE CODE WHICH I AM USING....

Comment: Post your html and js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand your issue properly but If you want to submit two different form on two different submit buttons, then you can try as following:

suppose, you have two forms:

```
<form method="post" action="index.html" name="careerform">

 <form method="post" action="index.html" name="contactform">
```

then you can call `form.submit()` on two different buttons:

```
<input type=button name=career_form_submit_btn onclick=careertform.submit()> 

<input type=button name=contact_form_submit_btn onclick=contactform.submit()>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then, since you're posting to the same page, you'll need some logic on the destination, to see if either form is submitted, and then do what you will with the form fields (store in DB, create cookie, whatever).